# I would like to treat on the momentary table or inner table of oracle by making two or more values into a line.

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

Since I am a Japanese, I am poor at English. 
Please understand the situation.

There is the following as indispensable requirements. 
This requirement is unchangeable.

- I know only ID of two or more values.
- This number is over 500000.
- It acquires early at low cost by 1 time of SQL.
- The index is created by id and it is optimized.

The following SQL queries think of me by making these things into the method of taking as a search condition.

```
select * 
  from emp 
 where id in(1,5,7,8.....) 
    or id in(5000,5002....)
```

It divides 1000 affairs at a time by "in" after above where.

However, processing takes most time in case of this method. 
As a result of investigating many things, it turned out that it is  processing time  earlier to specify conditions by "exists" rather than having specified conditions by "in".
In order to use "exists", you have to ask by a subquery. 
However, it calls by a subquery well by what kind of method, or I cannot imagine.

Someone should teach a good method.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: select * from emp where exists (select * from (select 1 as id from dual union all
select 2 as id from dual union all
select 3 as id from dual union all
....) tmp where emp.id = tmp.id)Although it can do in case of this method, cost will exceed 10000.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to do this:

```
select * from emp where emp in (list of several thousand values)
```

Because oracle only support lists of 1000 values in that construct your code uses a union.

**Suggested solution:**

1. Create a global temporary table with an id field the same size as emp.id
2. Insert the id:s you want to find in this table
3. Join against this table in your select

`create global temporary table temp_id (id number) on commit delete rows;`

Your select code can be replaced by:

```
<code to insert the emp.id:s you want to search for>
select * from emp inner join temp_id tmp on emp.id = temp_id.id;
```